# Is there a way to check whether memory stick is broken?

Tags: memory, troubleshooting

[image]

The above is the memory stick I suspect may be broken,but not sure.

Because I can't boot up if I plug it in the slot.

Is there a way/tool to check whether the memory stick is working any more?

Comment: Probable duplicate http://superuser.com/questions/155615/windows-7-x64-how-can-i-test-my-memory

Comment: Those answers won't work since I can't boot up ...

Comment: Does the machine emit a series of beeps when you turn it on with the memory installed? If it does, you can find out what the beeps mean by googling for the codes for the bios of your computer.

Comment: I can't see the the codes for the bios of my computer when it fails to boot up.

Comment: The codes (beeps) are meant to be heard, not seen. Also, if you remove the memory, does the machine go through the motions of a boot up (shows bios screen) or does the screen remain blank?

Comment: Everything goes fine if I remove the memory.

Answer (score 1):

Try the memory in another slot, if it still doesn't boot it's defective. If the computer boots with the stick in another slot it's the slot that's broken.

Comment: I don't have another slot ..

Comment: @win - then you'll have to find another computer to test it in or borrow another memory stick to test in your computer

Answer (score -1):

What is most likely happening is that your USB drive has some sort of bootable file on it - which can be corrupt and your PC is set up so the first boot drive is removable media. This can cause timeouts and basically what looks like hangs.

If you can read/write to this from any machine, it most likely is not broken. You need to either change your BIOS to not use removable media or (easiest) format the drive then use it (to remove all system files).

If however no machine can read from the drive, it most likely is broken.

Comment: No,there's no USB driver on my machine.