# IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL Blue Screen

Tags: memory, bsod

I added new ram ddr4 2133MHz of different manufacturer than already installed 4GB ddr 4 ram recently in my HP laptop and I got this BSoD.

The PC performance is better than before but laptop's starting time is very less than before.

And I also got a very weird problem that is computer just stops sometimes and nothing happens (mouse keyboard nothing works) and I eventually need to press power    shut down

First Edit

Now I got another BSoD with stop code PAGE FAULT IN NONPAGED AREA

Second Edit

I asked them from where I bought it and they told me to use eraser clean the memory gold finger and also update the newest BIOS. What does this supposed to mean? What's there with BIOS to do with RAM and eraser clean?

Comment: Please show precise HP laptop model and RAM modles models, to avoid guessing.

Comment: @MikhailMoskalev It is HP Notebook - 15-ay190nia, and one ram is https://www.ebay.com/itm/SK-Hynix-DDR4-1x-4GB-1Rx16-PC4-2400T-Laptop-RAM-Memory-Module/122676160330?hash=item1c9011a74a:g:P54AAOSwaBZZppK1 which was already there and another ram is I ordered from china https://www.aliexpress.com/item/Kllisre-ddr4-4GB-8GB-2133MHz-2400-MHz-ram-sodimm-laptop-memory-support-memoria-ddr4-notebook/32848035913.html

Comment: @MikhailMoskalev Now it seems ok see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know much technical info but I just tell you what I did and my pc has no problems now with both pieces of ram.

1. I cleaned all dust in my fans (this may have improved heat related issues I guess that solved the freezing problem - this is just guess)
2. I did that eraser kind of thing and I don't know that solved the problem or not.
3. I used only new ram in the first slot and there there were no problems - it means no problems with single ram separately.
4. I added the old ram in the second slot and turned my pc on and it was running without problems but I haven't tested to full strength yet.
5. I looked for the bios update and actually the bios update was available and everyone saying it is risky if power goes down but I was prepared for that and there were a lot of bios updates available for different fixes and improved performances in HP website and I downloaded the latest update and went through the instructions provided by HP and my BIOS is updated successfully.
6. Then I tried to test computer in its full power, to do that I opened HD videos of youtube in three browsers and all are playing and at the same time I opened vitrual box and played another HD video in Ubuntu and at this time the cpu use rate was about 80%, ram is about 80% and disk 30% and it was running smoothly and I could indeed run another HD video in another browser if I had tried and I didn't see any BSoDs.

Now I guess this PC is stable with both pieces of RAM and if anything goes wrong ram related I'll inform here for future visitors.

I did all of those and I don't know what solved the problem. If you have any idea what could have solved the problem please comment below.

Comment: IMHO magic done my one or some of: 1. clean dust 4. Change modules order 5. BIOS update.

Answer (score 2):

From Microsoft's [How to fix Error 0xA: IRQL_not_less_or_equal](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/4028391/windows-how-to-fix-error-0xa-irqlnotlessorequal)

> This error means that something may be wrong with a device driver, your device's memory, or antivirus software on your device. Here are some things to try:

As your RAM is the related addition, that would be your first suspect.
Maybe try something like [memtest](https://www.memtest86.com). Check both sticks together & each stick separately.

Comment: What about that weird problem of mine. I'm typing with the same laptop now and any time the computer can just stop and nothing happens no matter what I try. And I need to press power button to shut down.

Comment: It's either related, in which case the same thing will test it; or it isn't, in which case it should be asked as a different question.

Comment: I'm thinking  to take that newly installed ram out of my pc and get another single 8 gb ram of the same manufacturer .

Comment: Are different manufactures are conflicting here? My first ram was may be 2400MHz (max-freq according to cpuZ) and new is like 2133MHz

Comment: noW i GOT another BSoD PAGE FAULT IN NONPAGED AREA

Comment: Stack exchange doesn't work like a live chat or 20 questions. It works on questions plus answers. Until you at least try my recommendation, we're not really going to ge much further.

Comment: @figureOut - If you have 2400 MHz and 2133 MHz memory modules installed, the 2400 MHz modules are being downclocked to 2133 MHz, the downclocking of the module is unlikely the source of your BSOD.  However, you could have an underline problem with the module itself, so using memtestx86 is still the solution to your problem (or will provide the required information to answer your question).  I am answering your last question, only so you will provide the information, required to answer your question.  **Please do not submit additional comments indicating you got another BSOD.**

Comment: @Ramhound, Not neccessary 2400 MHz module is downclocked, some vendors can lock RAM clock in BIOS/UEFI

Comment: Besides of RAM clock, RAM timings can have matter and also can be locked by vendor.

Comment: Multiple BSoDs and freezing problem are enough to freak me out and I'm not willing to think about another damn test, memory diagnostic did not find errors. I just took the damn ram out and my pc has no problems. Less ram it is but it is running smoothly and no headache. It is far better than before and no crash :)

Answer (score 1):

It almost definitely RAM problem. Possible RAM imcompatibility with Notebook or with other RAM module.

For branded hardware, like HP, is safer to use RAM modules from vendor verified compatibility list for Your laptop model.

**UPD:**

Modern Windows have builtin memory test.

[How to detect bad RAM with the Windows Memory Diagnostic tool](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-detect-bad-ram-with-the-windows-memory-diagnostic-tool/)

> 1. Open the Control Panel
> 2. Click Administrative Tools
> 3. Click Windows Memory Diagnostic. [You can also launch the tool by entering "mdsched" in the search bar.]
> 4. Select "Restart now and check for problems" or "Check for problems the next time I start my computer" [If you opt to restart and run the
>      tool now, just be sure to save your work and close any open programs
>      for before doing so.]
> 5. Select your memory test options and run the test [Once the machine restarts, the tool will launch and run the memory test. You can press
>      F1 to change the test options or just let it run with the standard
>      settings.]
> 6. Let the test run [The test could take a few minutes.]

Related Superuser:

- [Windows 7 x64 - How can I test my memory?](https://superuser.com/q/155615/17118)

PS:

BSOD nd application crashes can be different and random, because of random nature of memory failures. So precise BSOD text is not relevant in this situation.

Comment: Memory diagnostic did not find errors, and I removed that ram out and I've no headache now.

Answer (score -1):

3.-4. Change modules order.. - This worked for me!
(first slots/new ram; second slots/old ram)
5. Bios update.. - maybe