# Wireshark crashes before opening

Tags: windows-7, crash, wireshark

I am running a 64-bit Windows 7 Dell laptop, and just installed Wireshark 3.2.6. Whenever I tried to open Wireshark, it would crash with the error message below. I've restarted my laptop, reinstalled the program, and Wireshark still crashes. May I know how I can resolve this?

```
Problem signature:
Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
Application Name:   Wireshark.exe
Application Version:    3.2.6.0
Application Timestamp:  5f3431f4
Fault Module Name:  ntdll.dll
Fault Module Version:   6.1.7601.18798
Fault Module Timestamp: 5507b864
Exception Code: c0000005
Exception Offset:   00000000000276e9
OS Version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
Locale ID:  1033
Additional Information 1:   6146
Additional Information 2:   6146a616132120fbef8950de6627b310
Additional Information 3:   00f8
Additional Information 4:   00f862fb85021dd20481c97c75f09a77
```

Answer (score 1):

- is the new operating system fully up-do-date, including drivers?
- do you have any other programs crashing?
- try installing [wireshark 3.0.13](https://1.eu.dl.wireshark.org/win64/Wireshark-win64-3.0.13.exe) instead. still crashing?
- since you reinstalled Windows, one can assume the system is healthy, therefore a [system scan](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/929833/use-the-system-file-checker-tool-to-repair-missing-or-corrupted-system) should not detect any anomalies.
- you may also want to [test your computer's memory](https://superuser.com/questions/155615/windows-7-x64-how-can-i-test-my-memory) for anomalies.

Comment: I have just updated the laptop, no other program was crashing. I did the sfc scan, and it did report repairing some files. Anyway, I tried installing version 2.6.18, it crashed too. I then installed 2.0.4, and finally it works. So it seems like only older versions of Wireshark works.

Comment: Very strange that you have problems reported by sfc scan, you should check the computer's memory and the hard drive for issues. For hard drive testing, I would recommend [hdtune](https://hdtune.com/) free version will do. Check the `Error Scan` and `Health` tabs.